# Show that the matrix representation of the inverse transformation is $Y^T$ and that $Y^T = Y^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm already given the matrix representations of the yaw, pitch, and roll. Am I supposed to just find the inverse of them? If so, my teacher has not ever had us calculate it the "traditional" way. Instead, we just performed row operations to get it, which I think is impossible here because of the variables in the matrices.

Comment: Can you construct Y?

Comment: $Y$ = $\begin{bmatrix}cos(u) & sin(u) & 0\\-sin(u) & cos(u) & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Can you show that $Y*Y^{T}=I$

Comment: Just tried this and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ rotations  are represented by orthogonal matrices ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#Orthogonal_and_rotation_matrices)) because a rotation transform a orthonormal basis to another orthonormal basis, so, your matrix $Y$ that represent e rotation around some axis, is orthogonal. And for [orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) we have $Y^T=Y^{-1}$ .

Comment: So, if the determinant is plus or - 1, then the matrix is orthogonal, making $Y^T$ = $Y^{-1}$?

Comment: No. The fact that $\det A=\pm1$ is not sufficient. The iff condition is that the rows of the matrix form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Sorry. I see that my answer was not clear, so I've changed it. I hope that it's better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We haven't covered orrthonormal bases much in class, so I went a different route and realized that Y * its transpose gets the identity matrix, meaning the inverse is the transpose.